# how to show random two li in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Could you please tell me how to show random two `li` in `jQuery` ? I tried like this

```js
$('#id_show12').click(function() {
    var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    $('.show12 li').not(':eq(' + random1 + '), :eq(' + random2 + ')').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show12">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="id_show12">show only one two li</button>
```

https://jsbin.com/dafurasaye/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset to show all the elements, then run your logic over it, see below

```js
$('#id_show12').click(function() {
  var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

  $('.show12 li')
    .show() /* <-- reset */
    .not(':eq(' + random1 + '), :eq(' + random2 + ')')
    .hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show12">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="id_show12">show only one two li</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You all logic works great when you show before you hide them.

```
$('.show12 li').show();
$('.show12 li').not(':eq('+random1+'), :eq('+random2+')').hide();
```

Currently it is not working because you are hiding them and not showing them back when you click again.

**Note that you are not handling the case when the random numbers are same. (0,0 | 3,3)** If you don't handle the case, sometimes it just show only one option.

Answer (score 0):

js code :

```
$('#id_show12').click(function() {  
 var random1= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);  
 var random2= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);  
 if(random1 == random2){
    if(random1 == 6){
        random1= 5;
  }
  if(random1 = 0){
     random1= 1;
  }
  else{
    random1=random1+1;
  }
}

$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
        if(random1 != index & random2 != index){
            $( this ).hide();
      }
      else{          
            $( this ).show();
      }
 });
})
```